# Downloading very large file causes the client to be disconnected at every 1:30-1:45 minutes

Tags: c#, file-io, download

Here is my code to download a file.

```
             Stream iStream = null;

            // Buffer to read 1K bytes in chunk:
            byte[] buffer = new Byte[ 4194304 ];

            // Length of the file:
            int length;

            // Total bytes to read:
            long dataToRead;

            // Identify the file to download including its path.
            string filepath = PathToFile;

            // Identify the file name.
            //string filename = Path.GetFileName( filepath );
                             Response.Clear();
            try
            {
                // Open the file.
                iStream = new FileStream( filepath, FileMode.Open,
                            FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read );


                // Total bytes to read:
                dataToRead = iStream.Length;

                Response.ContentType = ContentType;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + clientNameOfFile);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataToRead.ToString());

                Response.BufferOutput = true;
                // Read the bytes.
                while ( dataToRead > 0 )
                {
                    // Verify that the client is connected.

                    if ( Response.IsClientConnected )
                    {
                        // Read the data in buffer.
                        length = iStream.Read( buffer, 0, 100000 );

                        // Write the data to the current output stream.
                        Response.OutputStream.Write( buffer, 0, length );

                        // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                        Response.Flush();

                        buffer = new Byte[ 100000];
                        dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                        dataToRead = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                // Trap the error, if any.
                Response.Write( "Error : " + ex.Message );

            }
            finally
            {
                if ( iStream != null )
                {
                    //Close the file.
                    iStream.Close();
                }
                Response.Close();
            }
```

When trying to download a 50MB file, the client disconnects after every 1:30- 1:45 minutes. What are some of the things I should be checking which can cause the client to disconnect?

```
I have the following web config settings
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="51200" />
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="xxx:42424"   useHostingIdentity="true" timeout="10000" />
<requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
        </requestFiltering>
```

The IIS App Pool Idle Time-out is set to 20.

Comment: I presume this is the serverside of the code, How do you download the file? Do you use a C# client or a web client etc?

Comment: we don't use any web clients. directly writing the data into the browser

Comment: If you use `Stream.CopyTo` your code will be radically simpler and clearer.

Comment: @user2221069 - Do all clients disconnect after 2 minutes or only some?

Comment: only for large files, mostly around 50 MB files

Answer (score 0):

You have inconsistency in your code. you have declared byte[] buffer = new Byte[ 4194304 ]; in the beginning and change it to buffer = new Byte[ 100000]; in while loop. Also the length is not consistent either length = iStream.Read( buffer, 0, 100000 );